# HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed; doesn't fire up exception handling methods

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, okhttp

I have an RxJava chain request that should release some locks onError(), or onComplete(), so, basically, what my problem is: when I set read, connect and write timeouts to my OkHttpClient, I don't get the desired behavior. I'm using Retrofit2 and OkHttp3.6.0 Here's my simplified client:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
           .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
```

Here's a simplified version of the chain request I have:

```
public <T extends Response> Observable<T> doSomething(Observable<T> base) {
    isLocked = true;
    return someApiCall()
               .flatMap(apiResponse -> handleResponse(apiResponse, base)
                   .doOnError(throwable -> {
                       isLocked = false;
                   })
                   .doOnCompleted(() -> {
                       isLocked = false;
                   }));
}
```

`handleResponse()` makes another API call and returns an `Observable<Response<Something>>` but, as I've said, it sometimes fails with a `HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed` and it never finishes the Observable, so, onError() or onComplete() are never called. I've tried onTerminate() also, but with no luck. When I remove the timeout settings from the `OkHttlClient`, the `SocketException` is actually thrown and caught which releases the `isLocked` variable. I've tried wrapping the `handleResponse()` return statement with a `try {} catch (Exception e) {}` block, but even that doesn't catch the `SocketException` when the custom timeouts are set. Any ideas?

Comment: does the handleResponse do Retrofit call as well? what do you define as "finish the observable"? any how the problem might be as it's seems you're applying the doOnError/Completed just on the inner flatMapped called, thus - the someApiCall() can fail and you will not catch it

Comment: yes it does do a Retrofit call. As I mentioned it's a simplified chain, the real one should be originalApiCall (fails) -> apiCallOne -> apiCallTwo -> originalApiCall (it's a session renewal chain) I've tried adding both doOnError() and doOnTerminate to the outer call, but with no luck. The problem is that all other exceptions are caught in the chain, except for the Socket closed

Comment: ok, I see, so what do happen with the SocketException? how do you know that's the exepction?

Comment: I just get a one line entry in the logcat output that says exactly that: "HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed" and it always happens, it's not a false positive.

Comment: can you attach logcat ?

Comment: that's the only logcat output I get for the xception, the other things are irrelevant, I can see the call being made by OkHttp, but, for security reasons I can't share the whole thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the request was getting unsubscribed, which caused the appearance of the `HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed` error, so, the solution was just adding this code to the chain:

```
.doOnUnsubscribe(() -> {
    isLocked = false;
})
```

I still don't understand why the custom timeout value was triggering the `SocketException`, but I suppose that the socket was waiting for the timeout to expire and close, or complete the request and close, but it got interrupted by the `unsubscribe` call and thus closed unexpectedly.

Comment: So what's causing the "Socket closed"?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this situation in Android with the option retryOnConnectionFailure(true) set with the builder.

Given that Retrofit 2 just receive the OkHttpClient object.

Comment: You sir, made my day today

Answer (score 1):

In Retrofit 2, exceptions below/above the HTTP layer are not reported as `Response<?>`, but as actual exceptions via `onError`.

In your case, you should move the `doOnError`/`doOnCompleted` out of the `flatMap`; as it is right now they respond to errors generated in the `handleResponse` only - but that method won't be called if `someApiCall` returns an error Observable.

Comment: I'm aware of that and I've tried adding the doOnError and doOnCompleted to the outer call too, but with no luck, even doOnTerminate and doAfterTerminate, which are never reached (in case of the Socket exception). The real issue is that all of the other exceptions are caught by the chain, except for the Socket closed, which seems to be handled somewhere else...

Comment: Can you wrap the call in a `defer`? Like `Observable.defer(()-> someApiCall())`

Comment: Since I'm fairly new to RxJava, could you please tell me what good will this do? I'll try it out, but I don't know what to expect.

Comment: `defer` will postpone calling the `someApiCall()` method until the Observable is subscribed to. The idea is that you're doing something synchronously in that call that causes this exception; by `defer`-ing you sould catch that in the subscription.